# mysql specific 4 digit ID auto incremnate zerofill and add userpass as last 4 digit

Tags: php, mysql

my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `patients` (
  `patient_id` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pin` int(4) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `patient_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `patient_global_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `patient_dob` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`patient_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pt_global_id` (`patient_global_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

what i want is that the is to make the id column contain data like this

id:**4395** 0001

username:fool

pin:**4395**

---

and yet nextuser have id=PIN#0002 where pin column is auto random 4 digits

is this doable within mysql or i need to php it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)-function to get a random number:

As stated in the manual to get a random number within a specific range you can use:

```
 FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j – i))
```

Where `i` is the minimum number and `j` is the maximum number + 1. So to create a number with four digits you can use:

```
 FLOOR(1000 + RAND() * (10000 – 1000))
```

If you want to have leading zeros as well you can combine this with [`LPAD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad):

```
 LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 10000), 4, '0')
```

Comment: yet how can i add this to the id column+its ai?

Comment: You have to specify the "code" in your INSERT-statement. MySQL will evaluate it itself and you can easily switch programming languages or do bulk inserting like this, without relying on PHP. Automatically generating a random number, without specifying it is impossible as far as I know.